# FFMPEG frames are choppy when piping images to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working to optimize my rendering technique, it has some noticeable frame drops here and there. It's hard to tell, if you take a look at this recording you will see what I mean https://share.getcloudapp.com/6quxYe5O

My technique involves hardcoding a default FPS to be 25 and to use that to take a screenshot of the video every `(25 / 1000) = 0.4` ms inside a Chrome instance.

When I run `ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL_VIDEO` I get this output

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/storycreator.clips/e7d87660-51a8-11ea-a753-8f195b459e44':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6095 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6092 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
```

When I run it on the newly made video from the screenshots here is the ffmpeg output.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.testing/4aa5e5c0-3e89-11eb-a8b5-a38609fab693.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4775 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 4698 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Some slight differences. You can see the bitrate drops from 6095 to 4775. You will also notice audio was attached in the new one. The video size changed -- this was intentional.

You also notice it go from `6092 kb/s` to `4698 kb/s` not sure what that means, open to clarification. Another change before that is `[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]` to `[SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1]` not sure what that is.

The last major difference I notice is `handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler` to `handler_name    : VideoHandler`. Very curious about those properties as a learning bit.

Not sure out of those changes which one is the most important for smooth playback like the original. I assume its bitrate.

Comment: *"When I run it on the newly made video from the screenshots here is the ffmpeg output."* What does *"it"* refer to in this sentence? I don't understand the workflow or how ffmpeg is involved here.

Comment: So I am screenshotting a video in a browser every 40ms. The screenshot is a .jpg buffer that gets passed into `stdin.write` which is piped to FFmpeg. Each screenshot is inside a loop and for each item, the screenshot happens and is buffered. Then it moves onto the next frame.